# Combining sum of two numbers from REST API (json)

Tags: python, api, flask

Blessings,

I have a REST API flask application which returns a JSON with the following through a POST request

```
{
    "you sent": [
        {
            "number": "5"
        },
        {
            "number": "10"
        }
    ]
}
```

My goal is to combine both sum of the numbers.. this might be quite simple but im at a loss :)

## flask app

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'about': 'Hello World'}

    def post(self):
        some_json = request.get_json()
        return {'you sent': some_json}, 201


api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

## main.py

```
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'
myobj = {'number': '5'}
mysecobj = {'number': '10'}

x = requests.post(url, json=(myobj, mysecobj))

print(x.text)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? Do you mean you want to sum the numbers you get from the POST request on the Flask API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to send your numbers like float or int:

```
myobj = {'number': 5}
mysecobj = {'number': 10}
```

Secondly, get your numbers from request, sum it and return back as result:

```
def post(self):
    some_json = request.get_json()
    number1 = some_json[0]['number']
    number2 = some_json[1]['number']
    _sum = number1 + number2
    return {'result': _sum}, 201
```

Comment: I named _sum with underscore because python has built-in function sum

Answer (score -1):

This code is ugly but functional. I suggest you find a nicer format of sending data in future but this works given the objects you have.

```
dic = {
    "you sent": [
        {
            "number": "5"
        },
        {
            "number": "10"
        }
    ]
}

sum = int(dic["you sent"][0]["number"]) + int(dic["you sent"][1]["number"])
print(sum)
```